# How to get package name from apk in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app which will contain a list of Apps. On click the user will be redirected to the Play Store to download this app. On successful download I have to send that apps package name to a server to validate it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do this at runtime, so your app can read its own package_id w/o having this hardcoded. For that you need to use `PackageManager`'s `getPackageInfo()` method:

```
protected String getPackageName() {
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager.getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);

        return packageInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStacktrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: no not my own app info I want to get package name of app download via my app from play store

Comment: @niraj you need to rework your question as it is not clear. You said `I am developing an app which will contain a list of Apps.` - so if you got list of apps why not store Ids in that list too?

Answer (score 0):

Use [apkanalyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apkanalyzer), its part of the Android studio:

```
apkanalyzer manifest application-id path/to/apk/file.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

When installing the application. `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`
[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)
`BroadcastReceiver` method `onReceive`

```
val packageManager = context.packageManager
val uId = intent.getIntExtra(Intent.EXTRA_UID, -1)
val packageName = packageManager.getPackagesForUid(uId)?.first() ?: return
```

When uninstalled the application. `ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED` or `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`
[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED)

```
val packageName = intent.data?.schemeSpecificPart ?: return
```

Get app name or icon

```
val applicationInfo = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
  packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.ApplicationInfoFlags.of(0))
} else {
  @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
  packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0)
}

val appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo)
val appIcon = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(applicationInfo)
```

**Attention**
When installing the application, if use `intent.data?.schemeSpecificPart` not on all devices the correct one is returned package name.