# How to get package name of any application after successful installation in android?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I am devloping an app that contain list of app ,what I have to do is when user click on particular app he will be redirected to google play store and after successful download of that app I have to get package name of that app for this I am using broadcast receiver.But this receiver get package name of every app whenever new app is download in device .But I only want to get package name of that app which is listed in my app .

Comment: but this example get package name of that aap only when insatlled or uninstall

Comment: already in stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768091/how-to-get-package-name-from-apk-in-android/36768301#36768301

Comment: yes  I want if any app from my list is download get package name of that

Comment: ok so you need a `BroadcastReceiver` listening for an action `Intent#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`

Comment: how to add a `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: yes thats what I was asking

Comment: read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html#ActivatingComponents)

Answer (score 5):

```
    @Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    PackageManager pm;
    pm = getPackageManager();

    //get a list of installed apps.
    packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {

        PAKAGE_NAME = packageInfo.packageName contains package name

    }
```

Comment: this show my app name whenevr install or unnstall

Answer (score 0):

Use `getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).packageName`

You can also create a function for this:

```
public String getPackageName(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageName();
}
```

Comment: but this will give my app package name only,I want whenever particular app is successful downloded get that package name ,try to understand